# Using _.after() in async callback, polluting array variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I hope this question is not a duplicate, I have searched similar question here but got no matching result.

In **node.js** Below code is polluting the `storage` variable. And I really can't figure out why.

```
var _ = require('underscore'); // same result by using lodash

function add(arr, callback) {
    var l = arr.length,
        storage = [];

    function doCallback() {
        callback(storage);
    }

    returnStorage = _.after(l, doCallback);
    _.each(arr, function (a) {
        _.delay(function () {
            storage.push(a);
            returnStorage();
        }, 10);
    });
}

function callbackHandler(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

add([1,2,3], callbackHandler),
add([4,5,6,7], callbackHandler);

// in console will print wrong result:
// [ 4 ]
// [ 4, 5 ]
// [ 4, 5, 6 ]
// [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

However if I don't use `_.after()` it will give the expected result. Using **underscore** or **lodash** give same result.

Below code is working fine.

```
var _ = require('underscore'); // same result by using lodash

function add(arr, callback) {
    var l = arr.length,
        storage = [];

    function returnStorage() {
        if (storage.length == l) {
            callback(storage);
        }
    }

    _.each(arr, function (a) {
        _.delay(function () {
            storage.push(a);
            returnStorage();
        }, 10);
    });
}

function callbackHandler(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

add([1,2,3], callbackHandler),
add([4,5,6,7], callbackHandler);

// in console will print correct result:
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
// [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

How should i identify the root cause !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic of javascript's context. When you are doing:

```
returnStorage = _.after(l, doCallback);
```

`returnStorage` is the same for your second call of `add`.

You need to declare it with `var` to make it new and local to the function.

```
var _ = require('underscore'); // same result by using lodash

function add(arr, callback) {
    var l = arr.length,
        storage = [];

    function doCallback() {
        callback(storage);
    }

    var returnStorage = _.after(l, doCallback);
    _.each(arr, function (a) {
        _.delay(function () {
            storage.push(a);
            returnStorage();
        }, 10);
    });
}

function callbackHandler(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

add([1,2,3], callbackHandler),
add([4,5,6,7], callbackHandler);

// in console:
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
// [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

#### Bit of explanation:

On your first call of `add()`, `returnStorage` is `undefined`. It will then be defined it the global context since their is no `var` before it.

On your second call, the variable is declared, and when you set it, you also set it for the first `add()` call. So after the 10ms each elements of `[1,2,3]` have called `returnStorage` (the second one) and the next element of `[4,5,6,7]` will trigger the `returnStorage` callback, any further calls will also triggers  it.

Comment: You're right. From now on, I will put 'use strict' to all my modules, to avoid this mistake on the future.